# unable to import numpy library in jupyter notebbok even if it was installed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I run into this problem in the following picture while importing numpy into jupyter notebook.
Please help:

[image]

Here is print(sys.path):
[image]

Comment: Restarting the kernel can help

Comment: I did, I closed the notebook and restarted.and it still wouldn't load numpy

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `print(sys.path)`?

I have had trouble with jupyter and multiple instances of python in the past. pip installing to one python and running jupyter on another python.

(This should probably be a comment, but I can't comment)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall numpy('pip uninstall numpy') then again reinstall ('pip install numpy').